# SSH via DNS permission denied, but it works via IP (Debian 8.3)

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, debian, port-forwarding

I have a server behind a router, and I have forwarded port 22 (TCP/UDP). I can SSH to the IP (ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) but not to the DNS (ssh user@mysite.com). I'm getting:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I have verified that the DNS is indeed leading to the server by turning it off (in which case I get no response trying SSH). I have tried forcing SSH over IPv4 using the DNS, but it doesn't seem to be the issue. I have tried "UseDNS no" and "GSSAPIAuthentication no" to no avail.

`var/log/secure` is empty. Looking at `var/log/auth.log` I can see from the same minute I tried to connect that:

```
Mar  8 21:47:00 myhost sshd[1033]: Received disconnect from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 11: disconnected by user
Mar  8 21:47:00 myhost sshd[1031]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user myuser
Mar  8 21:47:08 myhost sshd[1052]: Connection closed by xx.xxx.xxx.xxx [preauth]
```

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure` for possible errors?

Comment: My guess is there's something in `.ssh/config` that's doing something specific to the hostname.

Comment: Also check /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow restrictions

Comment: Oh, I'm so stupid... it was ~/.ssh/config that messed it up on my local machine... thanks @Barmar

Comment: You need to first run `ssh -v user@example.com` look which IP address it actually connects to. Then `ssh -v user@192.0.2.1` (with the IP address which the first command connected to) and include both outputs in your question.

Comment: Please post answers as _answers_. They will not be seen in the question, and the question remains marked as unresolved until an answer is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change settings in

```
sshd_config
```

Change

```
UseDNS  yes
```

Kindly check the link below. I have added a screen shot for the same.

http://prntscr.com/aff5e7